# How to know the data consumption of android device within a very small date range

Tags: mobile-data, data-monitoring, nexus-6p, background-data

## Background

I watch my data consumption religiously, since the telcom operators in Lebanon charge an arm and a leg for every MB spent. The bundles cost ok, but when you exceed the bundle they charge you like 6 cents a MB.

What happened last month is that I eventually exceeded my 20GB bundle *at May 12, 8:12 AM*, so I immediately turned off my data usage on my android, and tried to upgrade the bundle. It turns out that the operator system was down. I called them, they said keep your data turned off until the system is back up again.

So eventually the system got back and I upgraded my data bundle *at May 13, 1:53PM*.

## Problem

Come monthly bill time, I got charged crazy cash. I called them and they claimed that I consumed 3.6GB worth of extra data! Now the above is my side of the story, I would like to prove it using the data manager of my android device

The data manager of my android device shows consumption per cycle (which is defined by me, i set it at the 16th of every month since my billing cycle with my telco operator ends at the 15th midnight).

## Question

What I would like to do is basically *zoom in* the data usage report and basically see exactly how much was consumed between May 12, 8:12AM and May 13, 1:53PM. Is that possible using android settings natively or through a third party software? Please bear in mind that this must be done to *historical* data, not from future data as it's impossible to predict the future.

## Tech Details

My phone is Nexus 6p running Android 7.1.2

[image][image]